# How to Convert Oracle Number(19) to Java Long?

Tags: java, oracle, spring-jdbc

**How to Convert Oracle Number(19) to Java Long ?** 
*(Number(19) means equivalent to java Long as per this https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19501-01/819-3659/gcmaz/)*

I don't want to use Long.parseLong or Long.valeOf as both throws exceptions. 
Here is my data in DB

```
 ColName (Foreign key, Nullable)
 1
 null
 100325
 null
```

Here are the alternative I tried 
1)  `program.setXX(rs.getLong("colName"))`

 It returns values (1,0,100325,0). *null values are replaced with 0*

2) `program.setXX((Long)rs.getObject("colName"));`

3) `program.setXXX(Long.parseLong(rs.getString("colName")));`

4) `program.setXXX(Long.valueOf(rs.getString("colName")));`

 These above 3 throws exception, And My POJO setter accept Long.

I am expecting result like **(1,null,100325,null)**, Whenever DB has null value , Java should  hold it, And Whenever DB has long value(non null) , Java should  hold it.

I am doing this in spring JDBC template RowMapper, 
**Is there any alternative for above steps?** like Some Apache Utility method or Spring inbuilt method.

Comment: You are looking for an **alternative to what**? Please show your source code so far.

Comment: Can you please rephrase your question ?

Comment: Use the [getObject()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getObject-int-) method of `ResultSet`.

Comment: It seems as if you're trying to parse a String to long instead of actually getting a long from your ResultSet using getLong(). Alternative implementations for parsing numbers are also available in Apache Lang's NumberUtils. Those are not throwing an exception but instead will return a default. But I doubt that's actually the problem you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either catch the exception and handle it in a way that is suitable for your application (ex setting the long value to 0) or check if the value is null first before using longValue().

```
Long value = ....
long result;
if (value == null)
{
    // Deal with this situation in a way appropriate for your application
}
else
{
    result = value.longValue();
    // Use the result
}
```

**Edit:**

I think I understand your confusion.

In Java, primitive types are things like `int`, `boolean`, or `long`. These are native types and **cannot store null values**. Only object types like `String`, `Long` (notice the capital), or `Scanner` can store a null value. So, if you have a function that's accepting a `long`, then you won't be able to pass it a null value because `long`s cannot store a null value. Either the function accepting a `long` needs to be modified to accept an object, like `Long`, or you need to handle the `null` situation yourself.

There is no other alternative.

Comment: I don't want manual code for this, i am looking for some utility method. Please re look my question, i have updated it.

Comment: Thanks for understanding my view,For now I will use your suggested way as there is no other option.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
ResultSet rs;
...
Long aLong = rs.getLong("MY_COLUMN");
if ( rs.wasNull() ) {
    aLong = null;
}
```

This example assumes Java 5 at least (auto boxing).  If you're not on Java 5, you'll have a little more work to get the long into a Long.

Also, note that it is possible to store numbers in an Oracle NUMBER(19) field that exceed Java's max value for a long.

Comment: This method convert null values into 0, i don't want this behavior. Please re look my question, i have updated it.

Comment: You use rs.wasNull() for that.  I'll update my answer.

Comment: I liked your alternative as there is no readymade alternative.